# MapInfo Labelling by Expression

Tags: labeling, mapinfo

I have a table with 6 columns (Integer) containing licence numbers.

I would like to label the data using only the columns containing a licence number and not have a label for the columns containing a 0 (zero) attribute.

The column PRIMARY_LICENCE_NUMBER contains only licence numbers but the other columns have a mixture of licence numbers and a zero, reducing until License_6 has no licence numbers and only zeros.
The largest licence number is 118001 and the smallest is 11001.

I want to label in this order:
PRIMARY_LICENCE_NUMBER,License_2,License_3,License_4,License_5,License_6

I have read your other answers with expressions containing Left$ and Int and have not had any luck working out an expression that works.

My bumbling attempt is at this stage:

```
"L1: "+PRIMARY_LICENCE_NUMBER+Chr$(13)+"L2: "+Left$(License_2, Len(License_2)*Int(License_2<>0))
```

and all variations in between, and I can't figure out how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your *License_n* fields are integers:

```
"L1: "
+PRIMARY_LICENCE_NUMBER
+Chr$(13)
+"L2: "
+Left$(Str$(License_2), Len(Str$(License_2))*Int(License_2>0))
```

or better:

```
"L1: "
+PRIMARY_LICENCE_NUMBER
+Chr$(13)
+Left$(Str$("L2: "+License_2), Len(Str$("L2: "+License_2))*Int(License_2>0))
```

(prefix L2: does not need to be visible if there is no license number)

... and you can continue with this pattern.